# Retrieve Array data through json

Tags: arrays, json

I want to retrieve related_ids array's data, but fail to do so. My code does not give me each value of array separately.

```
  {
  "title": "Prod"
  "related_ids": [3]
  0:  4323
  1:  4321
  2:  4317
  "tags": [0]
  }
```

This is my code.

```
    JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("showProductListResponse");

    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        try {
            JSONObject obj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            HomelList productListItems = new HomelList();

            productListItems.setName(obj.getString("title"));                                     

            try {
                JSONArray relatedimages = obj.getJSONArray("related_ids");
                for (int j = 0; j < relatedimages.length(); j++) {
                    JSONObject relimagesObject = relatedimages.getJSONObject(j);
                    productListItems.setRelatedids(relimagesObject.getInt(relimagesObject.indexOf[j]);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            gavkidata.add(productListItems);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON-Data is not valid.

I think it should look like this

```
{
  "title": "Prod",
  "related_ids": [
    4323,
    4321,
    4317
  ],
  "tags": []
}
```

or if related_ids should contain objects change it like this

```
{
  "title": "Prod",
  "related_ids": [
    {0: 4323},
    {1: 4321},
    {2: 4317}
  ],
  "tags": []
}
```